# "tar --directory" won't work

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I want to create a tarball of files, but not include the directory name.  I know there's another way to do it, but I want to know why this way is not working.

If I run the following to create the tarball comprised of a specific file, then it works:

```
tar -vcf file.tar -C <PATH TO DIR> file1
```

However, if I run it on a wild card to include multiple files, then it fails:

```
tar -vcf file.tar -C <PATH TO DIR> *
```

I get an error saying, for each file in the *current* dir (not the dir specified in -C),  `tar: <FILE>: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

Any idea why running the above command on a wild card vs a file name behaves differently?

Comment: This is a better question for http://s.tk/unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` wildcard is expanded by the shell before `tar` is invoked. `tar` then changes directory (because you asked it to), but then can't find the files that were in the shell's current directory.

Of course, changing directories in the shell means that you can't open the output file in the original current directory. So you have to redirect the output of tar outside of the subshell, like this:

```
(cd $DIR; tar -vc *) > file.tar
```

Comment: Might want to add some quotes, and use `&&` to only proceed if the `cd` succeeds: `(cd "$dir" && exec tar -vc *)`; that way we aren't broken if the directory name contains spaces, we don't fork more than necessary, and we don't try to tar up the current directory if the subdirectory doesn't exist or we don't have permissions to cd into it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got the impression that this was on the command line, so a) I just prefer writing `cd $DIR` rather than `cd <PATH TO DIR>` b) chances are you'll tab-complete the directory anyway.

Comment: That addresses the first objection. The other two (particularly, the issue of the command tarring up the current directory if the `cd` command fails when `;` is used rather than `&&`) stand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a directory:

```
tar -vcf files.tar /path/to/directory
```

If your files are *in* your folder, then use the `.` to reference the current folder:

```
tar -vcf files.tar .
```