# tar: can't change directories to <dir>/<file>: not a directory

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I need to tar this dir - **totar**:

```
$ ls -l totar/
total 61388
 292 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was          298867 Apr 13 16:44 application.2015-01-19.0.log
 108 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was          109623 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-20.0.log
 788 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was          805468 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-21.0.log
1080 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was         1104861 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-22.0.log
2052 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was         2098782 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-23.0.log
   4 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was             455 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-24.0.log
21076 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was        21581073 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-26.0.log
9296 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was         9519026 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-27.0.log
17912 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was        18341302 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-28.0.log
8780 -rw-r--r--    1 wasext   was         8989019 Apr 14 13:32 application.2015-01-29.0.log
```

I created tarball file with parameter "-C":

```
$ tar cvf t.tar -C totar/*
tar: can't change directories to totar/application.2015-01-19.0.log: Not a directory
a totar/application.2015-01-20.0.log 215 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-21.0.log 1574 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-22.0.log 2158 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-23.0.log 4100 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-24.0.log 1 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-26.0.log 42151 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-27.0.log 18592 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-28.0.log 35823 blocks
a totar/application.2015-01-29.0.log 17557 blocks
```

I got this error: 
**tar: can't change directories to totar/application.2015-01-19.0.log: Not a directory**

In created tar file is missing file: **totar/application.2015-01-19.0.log**:

```
$ tar tf t.tar
totar/application.2015-01-20.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-21.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-22.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-23.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-24.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-26.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-27.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-28.0.log
totar/application.2015-01-29.0.log
```

Can you help me where I made mistake?

Comment: What did you mean by `-C totar/*`? What do you want it to do?

Comment: This question seems related... it explains that wildcard expansion is done before tar is executed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042963/tar-directory-wont-work?rq=1

Comment: I want to create tarball file from **totar** dir and its contain. So I understand that I have to use `-C` parameter. I tried `tar cf t.tar -C totar/ *` but it didn't work (now I see reason in your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042963/tar-directory-wont-work?rq=1 .

Comment: I understand that parameter `-C` is used if you don't want to change path to parent dir of **totar** and you create tarball file only from **totar** dir (and its content) without absolutely path. Because the **t.tar** file is moved to another server where is untared without absolutely path.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for [su] or [unix.se]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `-C` option to `tar`, you are telling `tar` to change to that directory first before adding files to the archive. This is very convenient to prevent having to change to that directory to begin with. Say you are in your `$HOME` directory and want to archive the files in `/path/to/totar`, then you simply give the `-C` option **to the directory above `totar`** and target directory. If you want to archive `/path/to/totar`, then you want to:

```
tar -C /path/to cvf somearchive.tar totar
```

**Note** the files spec above `totar` is a **directory name** not a filename and will include all files in the `totar` directory. You **do not** include wildcards, but you can include specific filenames. To backup only some files in `/path/to/totar`:

```
tar -C /path/to/totar cvf somearchive.tar filename
```

to only `filename` in the `totar` directory. (wildcards are not allowed)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works. `*` immediately gets expanded to whatever you see at the directory that you are in. So this command will almost certainly fail.

Comment: Your are correct. the `*` must be a directory not a file -- Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll see if I can make it clearer: When you enter anything with `*`, your shell immediately expands it to a list of files that match the patten.

So say you have a simpler directory: `totar` contains just 3 files: `foo`, `bar`, and `foobar`

When you then type:

```
tar cvf t.tar -C totar/*
```

It gets expanded to

```
tar cvf t.tar -C totar/foo totar/bar totar/foobar
```

Since `-C` takes a parameter, `tar` interprets the next argument, `totar/foo`, as the parameter of `-C`. And only `totar/bar` and `totar/foobar` remain as the files to be archived.

Do you really need the `-C`? Because I suggest leaving the `-C` out completely

```
$ tar cvf t.tar totar/*
```

**Update:**

If you want to retain the behaviour of `-C`, I strongly suggest that you have a look at @charles-duffy 's comments below.

Cheers

Comment: `tar cvf t.tar -C totar/ totar/*` won't work, but `(cd totar && exec tar cvf ../t.tar *)` will behave similarly, _including_ performance characteristics (since the `exec` means that the process table entry for the subshell is replaced with the `tar` process in-place, one isn't adding an extra `fork()`).

Comment: That said, personally, I'd skip the wildcard altogether: `tar cvf t.tar -C totar .`

Comment: While you were commenting, I tried it out and it didn't work, so I removed that version from my answer. But I agree, yours should work just fine.

Comment: The suggestion still present in your answer doesn't have equivalent semantics to what the OP is trying to do in their question, since it includes `totar/` as a prefix inside the tarball's contents; no point to `-C` at all if that's what one wants.

Comment: The problem then becomes that you need to give the files to archive as relative to the new folder, which makes it harder to use `*`. This is the tradeoff that you need to consider.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why tar is writing that _the mentioned file_ is not directory. :]